# How to store another table value using their id?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I have two tables with foreign key relation . How to store company name in employee table.
 in my view i have like this

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'Company_company_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(
        Company::find()->orderBy('Company_name')->all(),'Company_id','Company_name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Company','id' =>'cname','name'=>'cname'])
    ?>
```

controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Employee();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->save();              
        return $this->redirect(['index']);            
    }else {
        return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?=   $form->field($model, 'company_id')->dropDownList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->
                where(['id'=>company_id])->all(), 'id', 'companyname'),
        [ 'prompt' => 'Please Select Company']
        )
      ?>
```